# Angular Controller not finishing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Ok, so i am missing something. I keep running into issues like this. so obviously there is some foundational flaw in my understanding of angular.

I have a controller

```
angular.module('NextShift')
.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope','contactFactory',
    function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, $localStorage, $stateParams, contactFactory) {
       console.log("i get this far");
       function getContacts() {
        contactFactory.getContacts()
            .success(function(contactList) {
                console.log("why cant i get here");
                $scope.contacts = contactList;
            })
            .error(function(error){
                console.log("or here?");
                $rootScope.error = "Failed to get contacts";
            });
    }
}
]);
```

Everything is running and i am not receiving any sort of debugging errors. Yet my template is not populating with any scope variables. and the console log is not populating with any logs despite console.log lines.

My contactFactory

```
angular.module('NextShift').factory('contactFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
var url = 'http://myurl.example/api/v1';
var contactFactory = {};

contactFactory.getContacts = function () {
    return $http.get(url + '/contacts');
};

contactFactory.getContact = function(id) {
    return $http.get(url + '/contacts/' + id );
}

contactFactory.updateContact = function(contact){
    return $http.put(url + '/contacts/' + id, contact);
}

contactFactory.deleteContact = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(url + '/contacts/' + id);
}

return contactFactory;
}]);
```

So what do i not understand? It should at least be running the console.log functions... but... its not. This is part of an ionic framework project, i don't think that has anything to do with it though.

Comment: $http runs asynchronous so returning it will just return you undefined. You need to use the other handlers in order to get the information you want

Comment: Even if it was returning undefined, shouldn't i still be getting the console logs "why can't i get here"?

Comment: Try here for more information on how to use $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: You wouldn't get your console logs because you aren't passing the variable correctly so success and error are never called

Comment: Or if you are using it correctly I don't think your handler functions are in the right format try using then instead like the format the examples give

Answer (score 2):

`getContacts()` in declared as a function, but where is it called? You should call `getContacts()` somewhere from the controller:

```
angular.module('NextShift')
    .controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Auth', '$localStorage', '$stateParam's, 'contactFactory',
        function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, $localStorage, $stateParams, contactFactory) {
           console.log("i get this far");

           function getContacts() {
                contactFactory.getContacts()
                .success(function(contactList) {
                    console.log("why cant i get here");
                    $scope.contacts = contactList;
                })
                .error(function(error){
                    console.log("or here?");
                    $rootScope.error = "Failed to get contacts";
                });
           }

           // do something or other
           getContacts();
       }
]);
```

Adding a blank line before and after each function declaration really helps visually separating the code and helps avoiding such mistakes.

nb: if you want to call `getContacts()` eg. from `ng-click="getContacts()`, you need to assign it to a `$scope` variable like so:

```
$scope.getContacts = function() {....}
```

Note: I fixed your dependency declaration for the controller as well - your way would throw errors if you try to use one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

First off... you must claim your dependencies as strings (prior to writing the function)... all of them, and in the same order... so...

```
.controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope','contactFactory',
function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, $localStorage, $stateParams, contactFactory)
```

should be:

```
 .controller('ContactsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Auth', '$localStorage', '$stateParams', 'contactFactory',
function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, $localStorage, $stateParams, contactFactory)
```

Second, within your controller, you are going to need to initialize get contacts... Simply put:

```
 getContacts();
```

at the bottom of your controller if you want it to begin as soon as the controller loads.